# How to run m5threads?

Tags: pthreads, gem5

I was trying to run a simple pthread program on x86 SE mode.

Are m5threads the only way to do this?

When I try to compile `libpthread` using `make` I get the below error:

```
pthread.c:40:2: error: #error "spinlock routines not available for your arch!\n"
```

Is there something I am missing? Maybe some missing path variable or some minor modification of the code somewhere. Because I have the files `spinlock_x86.h` and `tls_defs.h`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to use m5threads if you're simulating x86 on an x86 host. gem5 has support for running code in shared libraries *on the host*. Thus, you should be able to compile your program with "-lpthread" and simply run it on gem5.

You may need to mess around with the runscript to get things to work. IIRC, you need to have the exact number of CPUs as threads and set the workload to the same binary for each CPU.

Comment: I used the command gcc -lpthread -o thread thread.c , but Its erroring out as follows /tmp/ccfigdKl.o: In function `main':
thread.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
thread.c:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
thread.c:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
thread.c:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status- I tried compiling it with -pthread, that compiles well but doesnt run with gem5 in SE mode.

Comment: warn: ignoring syscall set_robust_list(...)
fatal: syscall futex (#240) unimplemented.
Memory Usage: 583416 KBytes
I get this error while running it in SE mode after compiling it with pthread

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am also facing the same issue while simulating x86 in x86 host.